# When must one communicate denial of a shortcut?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel, mtg-regular-rel

Anthony begins his turn by drawing a card. He then immediately turns his creatures sideways and declares "I attack with [Runeclaw Bear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Runeclaw%20Bear) and [Alpine Grizzly](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Alpine%20Grizzly)."

Anthony's opponent, Nathan, has 6 life. Nathan has [Crippling Chill](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crippling%20Chill) and [Kill Shot](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kill%20Shot) in hand, and the mana available to cast either but not both. He has not yet acknowledged Anthony's shortcut to move to combat, nor has he denied it.

Which of the following is true?

1. Nathan must immediately deny Anthony's shortcut.
2. Nathan may deny the shortcut after pausing to think about what he wants to do.

I am specifically interested in two cases: Regular REL and Competitive REL. If the answer depends on which one is in effect, please cover both. I am not interested in casual play, but you can certainly cover that if you want to.

Comment: In competitive REL, this is not a valid shortcut. Anthony should call a judge.

Comment: @bengoesboom, How so?

Comment: @ikegami Probably because it isn't defined in the MTR as a default shorcut

Comment: @diego, A list of predefined shortcuts doesn't make other shortcuts invalid.

Comment: @ikegami I'm aware, thus why I didn't mention calling a judge in my answer, but I'm assuming that is bengoesboom's reasoning

Comment: @bengoesboom This is a perfectly valid shortcut.

Comment: Just to be clear, proposing a shortcut and acting on it by turning your creatures sideways are two different things. The proposed shortcut *was* valid. The actions taken in addition to that by Anthony were sloppy and would be reversed if the shortcut was denied.

Comment: Is this question about Nathan hiding information from Anthony? I could envision a situation where I don't want to interrupt my opponent immediately because I don't want to reveal unecessarily that I have some instant effect I could play in response to his attack.

Comment: @Hackworth Exactly. The end result is that Nathan is/isn't required to spill information about his hand.

Comment: The reason I said this is not valid is that it was not proposed. Anthony's opponent moved past any sort of proposal directly into acting, preventing Anthony from ever acting when he would have priority. At this point, the game state has reached a state (presumably Nathan passing priority in the "declare attackers" phase) in an invalid way. To correct the game state, you should call a judge.

Comment: @bengoesboom That is a good point. Calling a judge is always the right choice, but in my experience players often correct the game state on their own when it is as trivial as undeclaring an attack. However, I have seen bullies reply "But I already declared my attacks. It's too late." and *that* is when I see judges called over to correct the situation.

Comment: @Rainbolt And that is the correct time to call a judge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding shortcuts, the relevant rules for this scenario are:

> 716.1a The rules for taking shortcuts are largely unformalized. As long as each player in the game understands the intent of each other player, any shortcut system they use is acceptable.

as well as

> 716.2a At any point in the game, the player with priority may suggest a shortcut by describing a sequence of game choices, for all players, that may be legally taken based on the current game state and the predictable results of the sequence of choices. This sequence may be a non- repetitive series of choices, a loop that repeats a specified number of times, multiple loops, or nested loops, and may even cross multiple turns. It can’t include conditional actions, where the outcome of a game event determines the next action a player takes. The ending point of this sequence must be a place where a player has priority, though it need not be the player proposing the shortcut.
>
> 716.2b Each other player, in turn order starting after the player who suggested the shortcut, may either accept the proposed sequence, or shorten it by naming a place where he or she will make a game choice that’s different than what’s been proposed. (The player doesn’t need to specify at this time what the new choice will be.) This place becomes the new ending point of the proposed sequence.
>
> 716.2c Once the last player has either accepted or shortened the shortcut proposal, the shortcut is taken. The game advances to the last proposed ending point, with all game choices contained in the shortcut proposal having been taken. If the shortcut was shortened from the original proposal, the player who now has priority must make a different game choice than what was originally proposed for that player.

Regarding this specific question, when a player is proposing to do an action that can only be taken in a certain step that would occur after the player's last known step, it is a well-known shortcut that the player is going to change phases until the first phase where they can take that action. In this case, after drawing for Draw Phase, Anthony is proposing a shortcut to get to Combat phase, ending Draw phase and ending First Main phase without doing anything in either. This is a perfectly valid shortcut.

Once Nathan proposes this shortcut, Nathan is then allowed to propose a shortened shortcut, where he will make a game choice that's different than what Anthony proposed. In this particular case, the most likely proposal from Nathan would be to go until the 'Beginning of Combat Step'. This is a normal decision in the course of a game, and thus Nathan can take his time to decide on this proposal, within reason of course. This is the same at both Regular REL and Competitive REL. If Nathan takes an action before proposing a shortened shortcut, such as casting a spell or activating an ability, it is assumed that he is accepting the shortcut that Anthony proposed.

Note: Once Nathan proposes a shortened shortcut, Anthony is not then allowed to instead do something in his First Main phase; he has to go with the shortened shortcut. In this case, that would be advancing to end of his First Main phase and passing priority.

Comment: FYI - You have the names of the players flipped. **A**nthony is the **a**ctive player, and the one proposing the shortcut.

Comment: @Rainbolt Fixed, not sure why I didn't catch that XD

Comment: Awesome. Now I have a tough choice between your answer and Diego's. I usually wait a couple of days before accepting one, so we'll see where the voting goes.

Comment: Strategy nit: Nathan is better off letting it go to the Beginning of Combat Step so Anthony doesn't get another chance to play Sorceries.

Comment: @ikegami Good catch. Mind if I edit my answer with that?

Comment: Of course not. Go right ahead

Comment: It might be worth noting that the fact Nathan's opponent leaked information (what creatures are attacking) in declaring his shortcut is not Nathan's fault, and has no impact on the legality of shortening the shortcut.

Comment: @Patters It does not have an impact on the legality of shortening the shortcut, however, Anthony is not required to keep the same attackers once in declare attackers if Nathan does propose a shortening to before declare attackers.

Comment: agreed, I just wanted to mention the above because I have seen people object in the past, I have also seen people object to changing attackers after a shortcut is shortened, so if one is included in the answer, both should be!

Comment: @Patters To be fair, doesn't make sense to include either, since if arguing is happening between players, a judge should be called over, instead of the players trying to police other players.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing in the Magic Tournament Rules about timing when interrupting a shorcut. All it says is "A player may interrupt a tournament shortcut by explaining how he or she is deviating from it or at which point in the middle he or she wishes to take an action." So there is no reason you wouldn't be able to have a moment to think about it.

Obviously if you do anything that acknowledges the attack as being valid like casting your Kill Shot or otherwise using or passing priority it is too late to deny them their shortcut. Anytime prior to this point though should be fine, as long as you don't fall into Slow Play territory.

Personally, if I were Nathan what I would do in this situation is when Anthony declares attackers say "Wait, I might have something before declare attackers" and then once I have taken a moment to decide what to do either say "Ok, go ahead" or "Before declare attackers I..."